# webservice response "Unsupported Media Type" with POST method

Tags: java, ajax, json, web-services, jersey

I'm trying to understand Webservice in Java using Jersey.
I follow the tutorial: http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/json-example-with-jersey-jackson/

But I have some problem with my example.

Here is the code in webservice,

```
@POST
    @Path("/abc")
    @Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON,
        MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED
        })
    public Response createTrackInJSON(Track track) {
        String result = "Track saved : " + track.toString();
        System.out.println(result);
        return Response.status(201).entity(result).build();

    }
```

and here is from client:

```
var newTrack = {
                    title : "aaaa",
                    singer : "bbbb"
                };

             $.ajax({
                url : 'http://localhost:8080/Teamp3/rest/hello/abc/',
                type : 'POST',
                data :  { track : JSON.stringify(newTrack)},

                success : function(result) {
                    alert("success");
                    document.getElementById("lblRes_POST").innerHTML = result;
                },
                error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert("jqXHR - " + jqXHR.statusText + "\n" + "textStatus - "
                            + textStatus + "\n" + "errorThrown - " + errorThrown);

                }
            });
```

it will response:   "UNSUPPORTED MEDIA TYPE"

if I put :
                contentType: 'application/json',
                dataType: 'json',

in the ajax code, it still notice that message.
Could you please to give me some solutions for that. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change client side as below:

1. Change data :  { track : JSON.stringify(newTrack)} to data : JSON.stringify(newTrack)

For better suggestion, please sent us the network capture on network tab.

Hope this help

Comment: And another thing is why we need to add MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED in Consume annotation. I see in your code that you only send the json so I think MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED  should be removed

Comment: when I send a request to server, it automatically change 'json' to 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'.. so, I try with that MediaType. I will remove it. Thank you!

Comment: I have changed follow your advices, and add: contentType: 'application/json', I see the response in Firebug, it is correct,  but it go to error method, not go to success. The new error message is: jqXHR - Created
textStatus - parsererror
errorThrown - SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character. Do you know how to fix it?! Thank you!

Comment: I change dataType: 'json' --> text or remove it... It worked... Thank you very much!. :)

Comment: Np! I will update my answer for other guys facing same problem